# How to pass parameters in Javascript constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, this

In this code block:

1. if I declare `resolve / reject` with `const` keyword,

   I need to pass them into `executor` function without `this`, and using `this` will get error;
2. if I declare `resolve / reject` with `this` keyword,

   I need to pass them into `executor` function with `this`.

What cause this different behavior?

And what differences between these two ways?

Please help me, thanks~

```
class myPromise {
  constructor(executor) {
   
    this.status = PENDING;
    this.value = null;
    this.reason = null;

    const resolve = value => {
      this.value = value;
    }

    this.reject = reason => {
      this.reason = reason;
    }
  
    // Why not use this.resolve / this.reject ?
    // 
    executor(resolve, this.reject);
  }

  then(onfulfilled = Function.prototype, onrejected = Function.prototype) {
    onfulfilled(this.value);

    onrejected(this.reason);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not use this.resolve / this.reject ?

`this.resolve` wouldn't work because `resolve` is not part of `this`. Recall that variables declared with `const` are only accessible in block in which they are declared, which in this case, is `constructor { ... }` [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

On the other hand, when you say `this.reject` you are actually assigning that value to `this`, and have to use `this.` every time you want to refer to this value again.